# How to hide toolbar fully under status bar when scrolling recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, toolbar

I try to make scrolling behavior for toolbar as embodied in Google Photo. But my toolbar not hiding fully under status bar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library [Android-ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)

Whatsapp uses the same one

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to hide Tool bar,you can take help from code write below.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks{


    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDownMotionEvent() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (scrollState == ScrollState.UP) {
            if (ab.isShowing()) {
                ab.hide();
             //   image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else if (scrollState == ScrollState.DOWN) {
            if (!ab.isShowing()) {
                ab.show();
             //   image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    }

    ImageView image;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      //  image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ObservableListView listView = (ObservableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setScrollViewCallbacks(MainActivity.this);

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            items.add("Item " + i);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));


    }
  }
```